# QNap download station does not upload

Tags: download, nas, bittorrent, upload, qnap

I am using Download Station on my QNap NAS TS 253-B. I have been downloading a number of torrents. But the Download Station does not seem to be seeding/uploading. This is going to destroy my ratio at the torrent site.

The manual is annoyingly badly written, with no help on the QNap forum. What I want to do is seed infinitely and to an infinite seed ratio.

In Settings > BT > Bandwidth Limit I have made the settings shown in the image. [Screenshot of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0F6Q.png)

Just in case you're wondering:

- yes, there are leechers for the torrents I have downloaded.
- The Share Time maximum is 2 weeks or 'Forever'. I assume that means it
  will be shared indefinitely. Am I right or wrong?
- I tried to change the Share Ratio to a higher number. I assume that a higher percentage will increase the time the file gets seeded by Download Manager. Am I right or wrong?

Is there a setting that I am missing? 
I don't want to ruin my seed/leech ratio at my torrent account. Could somebody please tell me how to change this mess?

Thanx,

Thom

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your port(s) for incoming connections (see Settings) is accessible to external clients by trying to connect to the port at the IP address provided by your ISP for your router, using something like telnet command, or a web browser.

e.g.

`telnet <IP address> <port>
 http://<IP address>:<port>`

If telnet returns immediately, it failed to connect and therefore that port is not accessible to the Internet.

If browser says something like ' refused to connect' then then the port is inaccessible to the Internet.

If the port is inaccessible then you might try:
- verify that the port is open in your machine's firewall, and
- configure your router to forward connections received for the port to your machine's local IP address.